# Selenium other element would receive click but is the correct

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

Currently using selenium in java and trying to locate an element and click. It gives the error saying that the element is unclickable at point (x,y), Other element would receive click:

However  is the element I wanted it to click...

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Usually means something is infront of it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the standard `.click()` doesn't work.  I would recommend utilizing the `OpenQA.Interactions.Actions` class.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveToElement(element).perform();
action.click().perform();
```

This should execute the click at the given spot that you said the element exists.

Comment: Tried that too but had same error. Workaround I found was clicking on the element with an x,y offset.

Comment: Did you use Action class for x,y offset? Else, using the co-ordinates might cause issue when you run the test against different screen resolutions.